# Check if key exists is a JSON using Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to check if a key exists in Json file.
the key name is child and in some cases it exists and in some it doesn't.
example 1 -  key doesn't exists:

```
"customfield_11723": {
    "self": "https://ies-data-jira.ies.data.com/rest/api/2/custom/16110",
    "value": "DATA_MDM",
    "id": "16110",
    "disabled": false
},
```

exempla 2 - key exists:

```
"customfield_11723": {
                "self": "https://ies-data-jira.ies.data.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/16118",
                "value": "DATA_QM",
                "id": "16118",
                "disabled": false,
                "child": {
                    "self": "https://ies-data-jira.ies.data.com/rest/api/2//16124",
                    "value": "Installation",
                    "id": "16124",
                    "disabled": false
                }
```

The key path in the json file is ['issues]['fields']['customfield_11723']['child']
My code looks like this:

```
for i in todos['issues']:


    if i['fields']['customfield_11723']['child'] in i['fields']['customfield_11723']:
       print("True"
```

when I run this on case where the 'child' doesnt exist the exception is given on ketError:'child'

Comment: You can test if a key exists in a dictionary with the *in* keyword. Optionally you can try to access the key within a try/except KeyError code block. Another way is to use *get()* on the dictionary

Comment: You can change the query to `if i['fields']['customfield_11723'].get('child')`. This returns `None` if it's not found instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your specific case you would need to ask:

```py
# .keys() is optional but more explicit
if "child" in i['fields']['customfield_11723'].keys():
    print("True")
```

Personally, I'd try to use the walrus operator in combination with the `dict.get()` method in such situations:

```py
if child := i['fields']['customfield_11723'].get("child"):
    print(child)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the existence of the key by using the `keys()` dict method:

```
if "child" in i["fields"]["customfield_11723"].keys():
    print(True)
```

The `keys()` method returns a list of all the keys in the dictionary.

Comment: You can even omit the `.keys()` and it works as well

Comment: *if "child" in i["fields"]["customfield_11723"]* will suffice